# How to test a C# console application with selenium framework?

Tags: c#, selenium

I have to test a simple console program using Selenium. For example:

```
public class demo
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Selenium is a _browser_ automation framework. It's not for testing console or desktop applications. You can test web sites and web applications with it.

Comment: Selenium tests Web applications, not console applications.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't use Selenium to test console applications. Selenium is for automating browsers.

From its website:

> **What is Selenium?**
>
> *Selenium automates browsers.* That's it. What you do with that power is entirely up to you. Primarily it is for automating web applications for testing purposes, but is certainly not limited to just that. Boring web-based administration tasks can (and should!) also be automated as well.